# How to test nested ng-click using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an HTML which is something like this:

```
<li ng-show="obj.displayTab" role="tab">
    <a tabindex="0"  ng-click="abc($event)">
      NAME
    <div id="stdCloseButton"  tabindex="0" role="button"  ng-click="xyz()">
       PIC
   </div>
   </a>
```

In Jasmine test, I want to rigger `xyz()`, but even if I reach the nested `div` and trigger the click event,, it still fires `abc()`.

```
 var closeDiv = testElement.find( '#stdCloseButton' ).first();
 angular.element( closeDiv).click();
```

No Idea where to go with this. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. By design, an inline element (like an `anchor`) cannot contain a block element (like a `div`) only the other way around. The fact that you're not able to test this is an indication that something else might be wrong here. Consider using the following, valid, HTML instead.

```
<li ng-show="obj.displayTab" role="tab">
    <a tabindex="0"  ng-click="abc($event)">
        NAME
    </a>
    <div id="stdCloseButton"  tabindex="1" role="button"  ng-click="xyz()">
       PIC
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It actually works and is not invalid. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/